# How to split a PR into several parts if files are related?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I have a PR in GitHub that contains 17 files, and I want to split them into several PRs so it would be easy to review. But these files are related, if I remove one of them, Jenkins can't complete the build(e.g. Lack of dependencies or file not found) and checks won't pass. So in this way I'd like to know how to split a single PR into several?

Comment: Make the changes in different branches. Then PR each branch

Comment: Try not to think in *files* but in *functionality*. Create different branches/PRs for each functionality. It is OK if each of those branches/PRs needs all files, but almost certainly it does not need every line of every file.